# PHP script giving no such file or directory error

Tags: php, phpthumb

I'm trying to use this php thumbnail generator http://phpthumb.gxdlabs.com/ and i keep getting the error below.

```
Warning: imagejpeg() [function.imagejpeg]: Unable to open 'Images/uploaded/thumbnails/' for writing: No such file or directory in D:\Data\Websites\wamp\www\StephsSite\PHP\phpThumb\GdThumb.inc.php on line 672
```

Here's my script

```
 <?php
        require_once 'PHP/phpThumb/ThumbLib.inc.php';

        $options = array('jpegQuality' => 80, 'preserveAlpha' => true);

        try {
            $thumb = PhpThumbFactory::create('Images/Drew.jpg', $options);
        }
        catch (Exception $e) {
            echo "problems...";
        }

        $thumb->adaptiveResize(200,200)->save('Images/uploaded/thumbnails/');   
?>
```

and here's some of my file structure
testThumb.php/Images/uploaded/thumbnails

Comment: I don't know if it will help, but I always tend to have problems using relative paths with PHP-GD, I always have to specify everything using an absolute path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry, I have to ask: does the `Images/uploaded/thumbnails/` directory exist?

As a second thought, the error seems to also indicate that it's trying to open the *directory* for writing. Are you sure that `save` doesn't need a file name?

In fact, I think it does. From [this page](http://trac.gxdlabs.com/projects/phpthumb/wiki/Docs/BasicUsage):

> Saving Images: Saving images is pretty easy. You need only pass the full path to where you wish to save the image (including the file name) the the save function.

So, I would try something like:

```
<?php
    require_once 'PHP/phpThumb/ThumbLib.inc.php';
    $options = array('jpegQuality' => 80, 'preserveAlpha' => true);
    try {
        $thumb = PhpThumbFactory::create('Images/Drew.jpg', $options);
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        echo "problems...";
    }
    $thumb->adaptiveResize(200,200)->save('Images/uploaded/thumbnails/Drew.jpg');   
?>
```

Comment: Yep. I've checked like 6 times just to make sure

Comment: @Catfish, could you perhaps check one more time? No, I'm only kidding :-) See the update, online docs seem to indicate you need the full file name, not just the path.

Comment: It's because i didn't have a new filename. I just had Images/uploaded/thumbnails when i actually needed something like Images/uploaded/thumbnails/new_name.jpg. 
Thanks for pointing me to the documentation again so i noticied that.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you might want to change the path to Windows style, with backslashes instead of forward slashes.
Also, since this file will be written by apache user (thats how it works in *nix, not sure about Windows), you may need to make this directory world writeable and see if that works.

Comment: From what i've read, in windows you don't set the CHMOD like in unix. Im just trying this on my localhost using WAMPServer2

Comment: True, but even in Windows, if you right click on a directory, it would show permissions. You might want to give that a try.